# Combine tables with Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I was hoping to achieve this in power query. I have about 50 tables to combine. I would like to merge tables based on a column key. The problem is  some tables contain duplicates keys(Email in this case) but Table1 is missing values from Table2 and vice versa. Also, table 2 may be missing some columns or have an additional column. Open to other suggestions as well. Maybe VBA?

For example:

**Table1:**

```
Email   |   First   | Last   | Phone |
123@mail  John                555-555
234@mail  Timothy     Smith   123-456
456@mail  Jim                 123-456
```

**Table2:**

```
Email   |   First   | Last   | Phone | Location
123@mail               Doe             Toronto
234@mail  Timothy     Smith   123-456  Denver
456@mail  Jim         Barley  123-456  Cleveland
```

**Result:**

```
Email   |   First   | Last   | Phone | Location
123@mail  John        Doe     555-555  Toronto
234@mail  Timothy     Smith   123-456  Denver
456@mail  Jim         Barley  123-456  Cleveland
```

Answer (score 0):

With Power Query, you can do either a NestedJoin, or a Combine operation.
Either way, you'll have to extract the missing entries from the appropriate table.

In the example below,

- `Table.Combine`

  - Note that the Table.Combine argument is a **list** of tables, so you can combine more than two.
  - Examine the lines 2-5 for how I accessed the tables from the workbook.
  - Lines 2-3 were generated by the Power Query UI.
  - Lines 4-5 were manually entered by me, to show a different method of specifying the column data types.
  - It may be important to specify the data type as text for each column, as I did with `Table_2`, if you are going to aggregate dissimilar entries for the same email.
- `Group` by `email`
- Custom aggregation using List.Accumulate to extract the non-null entry.

  - Note that if an item in the same column from different table is not identical, you could modify the aggregation formula to concatenate the items.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    tbl1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Email", type text}, {"First", type text}, {"Last", type text}, {"Phone", type text}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_2"]}[Content],
    tbl2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source2), List.Repeat({type text}, List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(Source2)))})),
    comb = Table.Combine({tbl1,tbl2}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(comb, {"Email"}, {

    //Below are the custom formulas for each column
            {"First", each List.Accumulate(_[First],"",(state, current) => if state = "" and current <> null then current else state), type text},
            {"Last", each List.Accumulate(_[Last],"",(state, current) => if state = "" and current <> null then current else state), type text},
            {"Phone", each List.Accumulate(_[Phone],"",(state, current) => if state = "" and current <> null then current else state), type text},
            {"Location", each List.Accumulate(_[Location],"",(state, current) => if state = "" and current <> null then current else state), type text}
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

**Aggregation function**

- This will return the first non-null entry in the combined column table for the designated column

```
each List.Accumulate(_[column_header],"",(state, current) => if state = "" and current <> null then current else state)
```

- The `each` (and subsequent `_`) refer to the subtable of the grouped item returned by the `Table.Group` function.
- Although not in this forum, there is a good explanation of `List Accumulate` [here](https://radacad.com/list-accumulate-hidden-gem-of-power-query-list-functions-in-power-bi)